# I was going through this JavaScript code and I am supposed to do my task in jQuery. Now I am not able to convert this code in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to write this javascript in jQuery?

I was going through this JavaScript code and I am supposed to do my task in jQuery. Now I am not able to convert this code in jQuery.

```
function displayImage(i) {
    if(penguins[i]!="../images/yeti.png")
    {
        document.getElementById("penguin" + i).src = penguins[i];
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("penguin" + i).src = penguins[i];
        if(count != 8){
            setTimeout(myFunction, 500);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Congratulations!!.....You won the game");
            window.location.reload();
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by writing this code in jquery? the only change you can do here is to replace `document.getElementById` with `$` and add `#` to `"penguin" + i`. jquery is only adding some functionality to javascript so you can access and manipulate elements in an easier way.

Comment: Change this line `document.getElementById("penguin" + i).src...` to `$("#penguin"+i).attr("src",penguins[i])`